# Why don't the strings turn into integers?

Tags: python, loops, types

```
L = [['1','2'], ['3,','4']]
for innerL in L:<br/>
    for item in innerL:
        item = int(item)

>>> print(L)
[['1','2'], ['3,','4']]
```

Why do the strings of numbers not change into integers? If I type:

```
>>> type(int('3'))
<class 'int'>
```

then shouldn't the item be turned into an integer? What am I missing?

Comment: Fundamentally, you are missing how Python variables work. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You're just setting `item` to an int, you're not changing the values in the list. `L = [[int(digit) for digit in sub_list] for sub_list in L]` should work.

Comment: You have a typo in your question I think. `'3,'`... the comma should be outside of the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are integers?

```
L = [['1','2'], ['3','4']]
for innerL in L:
  for item in innerL:
    item = int(item)
    print(item)
    print(isinstance(item, int))
```

Output:

1
True
2
True
3
True
4
True

Answer (score 0):

The name used is only a reference; if you want to change the sequence then you need to change it directly.

```
innerL[:] = [int(e) for e in innerL]
```

Comment: Doesn't item in the for loop actually refer to the specific piece of data inside the list? If you type x = '3' then x = int(x), x will refer to 3. I'm still slightly confused.

Comment: @SpaSmALX: Long story short: "reference" doesn't mean the same thing in Python that it does in PHP and C++.